# Disable autocorrect form field custom search delegate

Tags: flutter

is there any options or ways to disable `autocorrect` for flutter search delegate > search field input?

Here the official documentation
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/SearchDelegate/SearchDelegate.html

Comment: Did you figure it out?